# Lorenz curve and Gini index using PDFs

Tags: calculus

I've been given that $f(w) = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{w}} $ for $0<w \le4$, and $F(w)$ is the associated CDF and represents the fraction of the population with income less than w.

I know that the lorenz curve is defined by $L(r)$ = $\frac{total \ income\  of\  the\  bottom\  r\  of\  the\  population}{total\  income\  of \ the\  whole\  society}$

and the Gini index by $\int_0^1{r - L(r)  \ dr}$.

I can't seem to get my head around how to calculate the functional form of the Lorenz curve. Any pushes in the right direction? (I've been told that the answer is 1/4 for the Gini index in this example)

I've worked out that $ F(w) = \frac{\sqrt{w}}{2} $ and so $ F^{-1}(w) = 4w^2 $.

Answer (score 0):

I think your F(w) is not correct. $\sqrt w$ should be in the numerator.

Edit: bold-printed corrected.
My idea is to calculate first the (linear) perfect equality line, $e(w)$. You have two points given: A(0/0) and B(4/**4**). When w ist 4 e(w) must be 4, respectively 100% (=4/4). So, e(w) can be calculated.

The area under e(w) is then $\int_0^4 e(w) \, dw$. From this area the area under f(w) has to be subtract:$\int_0^4 \left( e(w)-f(w) \right) \, dw$. The ratio between the area between e(w) and f(w) and e(w) is then: $G=\frac{\int_0^4 \left( e(w)-f(w) \right) \, dw}{\int_0^4e(w) \, dw}$.

greetings,

calculus